# Maze Hex Loops and Traps

Tags: mazes, network

The image should be self-evident..
Start at the blob pointed to by the green arrow.
Finish at the blob at the base of the orange arrow.
And you can only go one way (in the direction of the arrow!) along each path.

This shouldn't be too hard - it's here just for fun for those who like this sort of puzzle. [image: The Maze]

Comment: For complicated things like this it's highly desirable you make a machine-readable text version somewhere.

Comment: @parcly-taxel, honestly it is meant to look scarily complicated but it’s not so hard… 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this works:

> [image]
>
> There are multiple solution paths, but I tried to make it as short as possible

Comment: I hope you enjoyed it! I’m still learning a lot on how to construct these…